# How to avoid calling Jquery Validate on click of Cancel button?

Tags: jquery

On Click of Submit button only , i want to validate the form .
but this is also getting called on click of **Cancel** button also ??

this is my code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
        $('#pacinsertform').validate(
        {
                rules:
                {
                        pacname:
                        {
                                required: true
                        }
                },
                messages:
                {
                        pacname:
                        {
                                required: "NAME required",
                        }
                },
                highlight: function(element)
                {
                        $(element).parent().addClass('error')
                },
                unhighlight: function(element)
                {
                        $(element).parent().removeClass('error')
                },
                submitHandler: function(event, validator)
                {
                        if ($("#pacinsertform").valid())
                        {
                                ajaxInsertPac();
                                return false;
                        }
                }
        });
});

function ajaxInsertPac()
{
        alert('ajax call heer');
        return false;
}
```

this is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Luf0ks9b/32/

Could you please tell me how to resolve this issue , thanks in advance .

Comment: i even added formnovalidate  onto cancel button , but no luck .

Answer (score 1):

add this will fix the issue

```
$(".pacinsertcancel").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/umarmw/Luf0ks9b/33/